# publishing RDF (Turtle) using linked data Principles

Tags: csv, rdf, semantic-web, linked-data

I have following RDF (Turtle) file, this RDF is generated from CSV file using CSV2RDF conversion process by java language. I need to publish this RDF file on the web using linked data principles. How can i publish this RDF data on the web? thanks

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix csvw: <http://www.w3.org/ns/csvw#> .
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix dcat: <http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#> .
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<_:G> a csvw:TableGroup ;
    csvw:table <_:table0> .

<_:table0> a csvw:Table ;
    csvw:url <file:///D:\\Junhua\\10.5.2016 prototype\\tree-ops - Copy.csv> ;
    csvw:row <_:row0> .

<_:row0> a csvw:Row ;
    csvw:rownum "1"^^xsd:int ;
    csvw:url <file:///D:\\Junhua\\10.5.2016 prototype\\tree-ops - Copy.csv#row=2> ;
    csvw:describes <_:sDef0> .

<_:sDef0> <_:col[0]> "Ming" ;
    <_:col[1]> "Professor" ;
    <_:col[2]> "Celtis australis" ;
    <_:col[3]> "10k" ;
    <_:col[4]> "Software Engineering" .

<_:table0> csvw:row <_:row1> .

<_:row1> a csvw:Row ;
    csvw:rownum "2"^^xsd:int ;
    csvw:url <file:///D:\\Junhua\\10.5.2016 prototype\\tree-ops - Copy.csv#row=3> ;
    csvw:describes <_:sDef1> .

<_:sDef1> <_:col[0]> "Tang" ;
    <_:col[1]> "Lecturer" ;
    <_:col[2]> "Liquidambar styraciflua" ;
    <_:col[3]> "5k" ;
    <_:col[4]> "Database Management" .

<_:table0> csvw:row <_:row2> .

<_:row2> a csvw:Row ;
    csvw:rownum "3"^^xsd:int ;
    csvw:url <file:///D:\\Junhua\\10.5.2016 prototype\\tree-ops - Copy.csv#row=4> ;
    csvw:describes <_:sDef2> .

<_:sDef2> <_:col[0]> "Fang" ;
    <_:col[1]> "Assistant Professor" ;
    <_:col[2]> "Bangla text" ;
    <_:col[3]> "7k" ;
    <_:col[4]> "Semantic Management" .
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read the [Best Practices](https://www.w3.org/TR/ld-bp/) document.

Off the top of my head you should tweak your conversion process:

1. Eliminate some of the blank nodes, so that the data can be retrieved over the web. [Hash URIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/#hashuri) would be a good choice
2. `file:///` URIs are also no good, because they are meaningless for external consumers
3. You should include some links to other datasets like DBpedia or Wikidata. The links are what defines **Linked** Data

Finally, for starters the publishing itself could be as simple as putting your turtle as static content file.